# How do I make Typescript recognize my custom global filter?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I created a custom global Vue.js filter to format markdown syntax. That works well but typescript (or my IDE of choice PhpStorm) doesn't recognize the 'markdown' filter from within my component's template. It doesn't throw an error but I get no intellisense. Is there any way that I can drop some definition file somewhere so that I get intellisense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). Specifically, in vue, they have an example of [augmenting types for use with plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins).

However, the same principle applies to what you're doing here, so you would make a file -- say, `vue-shim.d.ts`, that looked something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MarkdownFilterTyping from 'wherever'


declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    filterMarkdown: MarkdownFilterTyping
  }
}
```

And now your `ide` should recognize that `Vue` has this method globally bound